# share view controller with uiactivityviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to add a share button to my app. Can I share a complete view controller so that when a user clicks on the shared link it comes to the view controller that was shared?

So far I have only found things like how to share images and text.

This is my code:

```
@IBAction func shareButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let items = [self]
        let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
```

At the moment I can only share a string.

```
extension DetailViewController: UIActivityItemSource {
    
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return "Test"
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        return "Test"
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You can't share the view controller. Use some deep link process.

Comment: can you recommend any source?

Comment: Use any of them: Firebase dynamic link, universal link, branch.io,  etc.
https://blog.branch.io/the-ultimate-deep-linking-tutorial-on-ios-11-and-whats-coming-for-ios-12/